# Contradictory boundary conditions in PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm asked to solve $\frac{\partial u }{\partial t} = k \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ with boundary conditions $u(x, 0) = 20$, $u(0, t) = 0$, and $u(L, t) = 0$, where $u$ is a function of $x$ and $t$; $k$ and $L$ are constants. However, the first boundary condition seems to contradict the second two, for example if we have $x = 0$ and $t = 0$. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe $u$ has two discontinuities on the boundary and its value at these points is irrelevant.